# Cannot press logout button using selenium

Tags: selenium, button, click

I cannot able to click the logout button using selenium (Python).
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMR2W.png)

Comment: What have you tried and post html web element code instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

To click that tag we can do.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[value='Logout']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to a frame, maybe the button located in some kind of iframe:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

After switching try pressing the button again.